# How to remove last part of string in c

Tags: c, string

I am doing a program in C, and currently I'm having problems. I don't know how to remove the last part of the string. For example:

```
char str[100] = "one => two";
```

I want to remove   `=> two`. Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give us more examples so we can find a one-size-fits-all solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove the part after a particular `char` token then use:

```
char str[100] = "one => two";
char *temp;
temp = strchr(str,'=');   //Get the pointer to char token
*temp = '\0';             //Replace token with null char
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, the string's end is marked with a zero character. Thus, you can remove the end of the string by writing a zero in the correct position:

```
str[3] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

find the place of the blank right after `"one"` and replace it with a `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

If the first part of your string always ends before the "=" and assuming it will always have the "=", you could do this:

```
int i = 0; 
char newstr [100];
while (str[i] != '='){
    i++;
}
strncpy (newstr,  str, i); //copy the i first characters from a char [] to a new char []
newstr [i] = 0;
```

Remember to include string.h to use strncpy

Comment: @rpattiso, I edited to fix the backwards problem and added a null byte at the end of the string. Thanks for pointing them out!